# How can I group columns of descriptive statistics in R?

Tags: r

I've been trying to create a descriptive statistics table in R - I'm pretty new to the software and am struggling to find a way to format the table the way I'd like.

At the moment I have this:

```
 data %>%
      select(Gender, age, Group) %>%
      group_by(Group, Gender) %>%
      summarise(n = n(),
                age.mean = mean(age),
                age.sd = sd(age))
```

Which gives me this (plus the numbers under mean and sd):

```
  Group       Gender      age.mean    age.sd
  Group.1     Male
  Group.1     Female
  Group.1     Missing
  Group.2     Male
  Group.2     Female
  Group.2     Missing
```

But this is how I'd like to present it:

```
                 Group.1                 Group.2
            age.mean   age.sd       age.mean   age.sd
  Male
  Female
  Missing
```

Comment: Can you show a fulll example of input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John says, the **kable** (and **kableExtra**) packages can help format the table when you have groups, plus lots of other nice features. However, getting the output in the requested format requires some reshaping.

I'll use the **survey** dataset from the **MASS** package.

```
data(survey, package="MASS")
str(survey) # showing only a subset of vars.
'data.frame':   237 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ Fold  : Factor w/ 3 levels "L on R","Neither",..: 3 3 1 3 2 1 1 3 3 3 ...
 $ Age   : num  18.2 17.6 16.9 20.3 23.7 ...
```

The goal is to get a table similar to this:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

Reshape the data using `gather`/`spread` and save it for later rendering by kable.

```
tbl <- survey %>%
  select(Sex, Age, Fold) %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  group_by(Fold, Sex) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            age.mean = sprintf("%.1f", mean(Age, na.rm=TRUE)),
            age.sd = sprintf("%.1f", sd(Age, na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
  gather(key, value, n:age.sd) %>%  #
  unite(Group, Sex, key) %>%        # Could have used pivot_wider...see below.
  spread(Group, value)              #
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   Fold [3]
  Fold    Female_age.mean Female_age.sd Female_n Male_age.mean Male_age.sd Male_n
  <fct>   <chr>           <chr>         <chr>    <chr>         <chr>       <chr> 
1 L on R  21.4            9.1           48       19.6          4.0         50    
2 Neither 19.4            1.3           6        21.2          5.2         12    
3 R on L  19.7            5.0           64       20.8          7.6         56
```

Note how the variables for Female appear before those for Male. If I had used:

```
pivot_wider(names_from=Sex, values_from=c(n, age.mean, age.sd))
```

I would have obtained:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   Fold [3]
  Fold    n_Female n_Male age.mean_Female age.mean_Male age.sd_Female age.sd_Male
  <fct>      <int>  <int> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>         <chr>      
1 L on R        48     50 21.4            19.6          9.1           4.0        
2 Neither        6     12 19.4            21.2          1.3           5.2        
3 R on L        64     56 19.7            20.8          5.0           7.6
```

Which are in the wrong sequence for our goal. I could rearrange, but why bother when spread can do that for you? Next, rename the columns. The `rename` function from **dplyr** won't allow duplicate names, so let's use base R.

```
tbl <- setNames(tbl, nm=sub(".+_", "", names(tbl)))
```

Then use `kable` to apply formatting.

```
kable(tbl, align=c('l', rep('c', 6))) %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Female" = 3, "Male" = 3))
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Is there a straightforward way of adding additional levels of grouping to this? So say with the survey data, if you want a table with n/age means/age sd split by sex (as above), but then above that split by W.Hnd (so you end up with 12 cols), and then also having rows for different variables (maybe this would be better asked as a separate question?!)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the kable and kableExtra packages particularly the "Grouped  Columns/Rows" functions like

```
add_header_above()
```

here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#grouped_columns__rows

Note: kable outputs not to console but rather to LaTeX, HTML, or several other formats.