# SPSS tables in R

Tags: r, report, spss

I'm trying to move from SPSS to R but I'm having some problems. I'd very much appreciated some help.
I usually work with the "tables" module in SPSS (I tried to post an image but it seems that I need more reputation). What I want is to be able to make tables for reports where there are 2 or more categorical variables (factors) in the header but without crossing them. And, in the rows, one variable. I should get the frequencies and the row and column total. And, if possible, the contrast tests. 
 Thank you very much.

Comment: Something like this: ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282295/how-can-i-group-columns-of-descriptive-statistics-in-r/61285940

Comment: It would be useful if you could supply some sample data which addresses your question. Have you had a chance to read [mre]? This would help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried to upload an image but I couldn't.  one example: I have a file with 3 variables. Gender, age groups and satisfaction rating. The scale of satisfaction is: "a lot", "quite", "little" and "not at all", for example. I would like to have in rows the satisfaction (4 rows in total) and in each column (in the same table) man, woman, 18-35 (age), 36-50 and over 50 years old, with the frequency and % in column next to the row and column totals. So, in total 5 columns, each one with two, frequency and %. And 4 rows, each one with one satisfaction rating.

Answer (score 2):

SPSS Statistics has Custom Tables, which can create nice tables with friendly UI. If you want to use R, you may need to install some packages, such as `expss` for instance. The following link 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/vignettes/tables-with-labels.html 
may be helpful.
Some other useful packages can be found here https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/ to make nice tables.