# Adding higher level groupings in summary statistic tables

Tags: r, kableextra

A while ago I asked how to make a grouped summary table: [How can I group columns of descriptive statistics in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282295/how-can-i-group-columns-of-descriptive-statistics-in-r)

I'd like to do something similar to this, but a few steps further, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
data %>%
  dplyr::filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  group_by(Type.Time, Type.Perc, Grp) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(mean.ms = sprintf("%.2f", mean(Time, na.rm = TRUE)),
                   se.ms = sprintf("%.2f", (sd(Time, na.rm = T))/sqrt(data %>% filter(Grp == 1) %>% nrow())),
                   mean.perc = sprintf("%.2f", mean(Percentage, na.rm = TRUE)),
                   se.perc = sprintf("%.2f", (sd(Percentage, na.rm = T))/sqrt(data %>% filter(Grp == 1) %>% nrow())),
                   ) %>%
  gather(key, value, mean.ms:se.perc) %>%
  unite(Group, Grp, key) %>%
  spread(Group, value)
```

This gives me the information I want, but in the wrong format and twice as many values:

```
| Type.Time | Type.Perc | 1_mean.ms | 1_mean.perc | 1_se.ms | 1_se.perc | 2_mean.ms | 2_mean.perc | 2_se.ms | 2_se.perc|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|---------|-----------|-----------|-------------|---------|----------|
| TType2    | PType2    | 703       | 15          | 15      | 1.4       | 573       | 8           | 22      | 1.3      |       
| TType2    | PType1    | 703       | 10          | 15      | 1.8       | 573       | 13          | 22      | 3.1      |
| TType1    | PType2    | 710       | 15          | 18      | 1.4       | 622       | 8           | 29      | 1.3      |
| TType1    | PType1    | 710       | 10          | 18      | 1.8       | 622       | 13          | 29      | 3.1      |
```

I'd like the top grouping in my new table to be the 1 or 2 (i.e., Grp [Group]) that precedes 'mean'/'se'. Then subgroups of Type1 and Type 2, with the preceding T and P being split as the rows (ms and % respectively)... So my aim is to produce a table in this format:

```
     |         Group1         |          Group2           |
     |------------------------|---------------------------|
     |    Type1   |   Type2   |    Type1   |    Type2     |
     |------------|-----------|------------|--------------|
     |   M |  SE  |  M  | SE  |   M  | SE  |   M  |  SE   |
|----|-----|------|-----|-----|------|-----|------|-------|
|ms  | [values calculated from 'Time' variable]           |
|%   | [values calculated from 'Percentage' variable]     |
```

I hope that makes sense!

Example data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Grp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Type.Time = c("TType1", 
"TType1", "TType2", "TType2", "TType1", "TType1", "TType2", "TType2", 
"TType1", "TType1", "TType2", "TType2", "TType1", "TType1", 
"TType2", "TType2"), Time = c(711, 711, 669, 669, 765, 765, 876, 876, 740, 
740, 658, 658, 456, 456, 423, 423), Type.Perc = c("PType1", 
"PType2", "PType1", "PType2", "PType1", "PType2", 
"PType1", "PType2", "PType1", "PType2", "PType1", 
"PType2", "PType1", "PType2", "PType1", "PType2"
), Percentage = c(8, 3, 9, 7, 19, 22, 30, 21, 10, 5, 10, 5, 8, 7, 
13, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to configure such header groupings is with the `kableExtra` package.

For the data preparation, I've made two main changes - only considering `Type.Time == Type.Perc` (to avoid the excess combinations shown in the question), and calculating the SE values per Type&Group (in the example code this mixes different groupings, which I assume is not intended).

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data %>%
  dplyr::filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Type = stringr::str_extract(Type.Time, "Type[0-9]"),
    Type.Perc = stringr::str_extract(Type.Perc, "Type[0-9]"),
  ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Type == Type.Perc) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Type.Perc, -Type.Time, -ID) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Percentage, Time), names_to = "parameter") %>%
  group_by(Type, Grp, parameter) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    mean = sprintf("%.2f", mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)),
    se = sprintf("%.2f", (sd(value, na.rm = T))/sqrt(n())),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(mean, se)) %>%
  arrange(Grp, Type) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = "parameter", names_from = c("Grp", "Type", "name"))

# A tibble: 2 x 9
  parameter  `1_Type1_mean` `1_Type1_se` `1_Type2_mean` `1_Type2_se` `2_Type1_mean`
  <chr>      <chr>          <chr>        <chr>          <chr>        <chr>         
1 Percentage 13.50          5.50         14.00          7.00         9.00          
2 Time       738.00         27.00        772.50         103.50       598.00        
# ... with 3 more variables: `2_Type1_se` <chr>, `2_Type2_mean` <chr>,
#   `2_Type2_se` <chr>
```

The values are already in the right format, and we can simply define several header groupings with `add_header_above`. And `kableExtra` [provides plenty of additional options for modyfing the output format.](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html)

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(df, col.names = c("", "M", "SE", "M", "SE", "M", "SE", "M", "SE"),
      align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r"),
      format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Type1" = 2, "Type2" = 2, "Type1" = 2, "Type2" = 2)) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group1" = 4, "Group2" = 4))
```

[image]